Mimic Google Form Submission through Apps Google Apps Script
I have a google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11B8qqCbzEk5Z4-rlGoJnB4Qfs68BdyHMx10DNai-j3Y/edit?gid=598497036#gid=598497036
and the associated google form is
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc57ziFTOo3HiYUi0OQaz8O2W6wvu5L5BU6maUl8V2VNn_tfw/viewform
I wanted to develop an Apps Script to mimic the form submission based on a given row's data rather than manually submitting the form data by a human. I needed this to duplicate form responses as needed.
I have developed the script for all the questions. And it is working too for all questions except for the last one (with checkboxes). I am having really tough time because all the check boxes in google form have same field IDs and I am unable to figure out how to feed multiple values from sheet (column Z) into the corresponding check boxes. As we know that the values entered through checkboxes are separated by commas in the sheet. My current script is only feeding the last checkbox value
I have explained the problem in this video
https://www.loom.com/share/5bddb51a3c9a4e0eb5e7ce88b8826d17
I will be grateful if you can help me as i have spent many hours trying to fix the problem but i am unable to do so.

Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365119/

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

I believe that you can call the onFormSubmit handler and provide the event object to the single parameter  usaully e is used.   And  get all of your data from the event object because the data will not be in the linked sheet.  You will have to create the event object like creating any other javascript object.  If you wish to know what is looks like you can used Logger.log(JSON,stringify(e)) in the trigger handler and perform a standard form submission

I have found the answer. I used the following code to get this done
// **Handling Checkboxes (last question) separately**
// Fetch checkbox values and filter them based on the options available in the form.
var form = FormApp.openById('1gFmmKPZ72O3l1hl93_rxhXwezPVqxNvGISEi7wnDP_o'); // Form ID
var checkboxesItem = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX)[0].asCheckboxItem();

